# 8relay module asks more than specs

Tags: arduino-mega, relay

[image]I have a 8 relay module that should use not more than 20 mA per relay.
Altough when measuring it asks around 70.
If I use 6 relays, that would be more than an Arduino Mega can give.
(I already lost 1 arduino here.)

How this is possible..?

Comment: What are you measuring? The input pins will be the low current pins, however the power supply pins will take more (and you can power those without going through the arduino)

Comment: Someone told me to give 5v en GND to the relais module not from arduino but from another source. Will try that.

Comment: I don't see why and Arduino mega can't supply 420mA from the 5V pin. It's also below the USB limit of 500mA.

Comment: please add a link to where you bought the relay module .... also add the schematic of the connections between the arduino and the relay module

Comment: Hello Gerben, it should be indeed possible for the mega but in practice it seems that the relays are asking more than the specs are telling..

Jsotola: will look up the fritzing

Comment: @jsotola I've uploaded a fritzing. This is the version which doesn't work. It means, powering the 6 relays from the arduino. 

There are signals coming from buttons that can put - if in the correct order - will cut of the power of the magnets which have external power.

The 8module relays says it doesn't need that much mA but in practice it is no solution. It keeps asking quite some mA.

Why it's not as the specs are telling?

It's this one: https://www.sainsmart.com/products/8-channel-5v-relay-module.

Should the module has external power too?

Comment: it is solved by giving the relay module power with external transfo. Not by arduino.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is solved by giving the relay module power with external transfo. Not by arduino

Answer (score 0):

Most of Arduino relay modules have a relay and a supporting circuit. The circuit connects the VCC line to relay coil if signal line is HIGH. Some relays have it conversely, they disconnect if signal is HIGH and hold the coil if signal is LOW.

Your relays need VCC which you can supply for 8 relays from 5 V pin of Arduino. This pin is connected over regulator to power supply of the board so it is limited only by power supply and regulator parameters. The power doesn't go over MCU.

The signal pins of individual relays should be connected to digital pins of Arduino. The signal pins don't draw much current since they only signal a state to the circuit of the relay module.